# Python - Ebooklib - Lxml: ImportError: Interpreter change detected - this module can only be loaded into one interpreter per process

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, ebooklib

We have a site where the back-end is in Python 3.x. We have recently added the ebooklib libray, in order to create epub books. Now we regularly get the following error:

```
    [Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.547413 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912] mod_wsgi (pid=21108): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/api/api.wsgi'., referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.547477 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912] mod_wsgi (pid=21108): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/api/api.wsgi'., referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549324 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549416 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]   File "/var/www/api/api.wsgi", line 8, in <module>, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549426 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]     from api import app as application, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549438 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]   File "/var/www/api/api/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549445 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]     import api.api.ebooks, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549456 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]   File "/var/www/api/api/api/ebooks.py", line 8, in <module>, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549464 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]     from helper_funcs.ebooks_creation import create_epub, create_pdf_with_html, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549475 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]   File "/var/www/api/api/helper_funcs/ebooks_creation.py", line 6, in <module>, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549482 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]     from ebooklib import epub, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549491 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ebooklib/epub.py", line 40, in <module>, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549498 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]     raise ex, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549539 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ebooklib/epub.py", line 36, in <module>, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549546 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]     from ebooklib.utils import parse_string, parse_html_string, guess_type, get_pages_for_items, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549556 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ebooklib/utils.py", line 20, in <module>, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549562 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912]     from lxml import etree, referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
[Fri Jul 28 00:35:40.549589 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 21108] [client 94.66.158.142:34912] ImportError: Interpreter change detected - this module can only be loaded into one interpreter per process., referer: https://oursite.ourdomain.gr/admin/SignUp
```

A google search led us to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895870/python-numpy-interpreter-change-detected-this-module-can-only-be-loaded-into). So we added `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to both oursite.ourdomain.gr.conf  and oursite.ourdomain.gr-ssl.conf and restarted apache. Didn't work. We also found [this](https://github.com/SAML-Toolkits/python3-saml/issues/121), which says to add `single-interpreter = true` to app.ini of uwsgi. Our system admin says we don't use uwsgi, and he doesn't know where the app.ini mentioned is to be found.
We also thought maybe it was a case of a circular imports in ebooklib, as it is rather old. The error seems to happen when epub.py imports ebooklib.utils. Both epub.py and utils.py have

```
from lxml import etree
```

at the beginning. So we removed the import from the beginning of the files, and moved it to each function instead. Also didn't work.

Any advice welcome, and also any clarification about the app.ini mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the system admin added `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to a third file, this time the api.conf file on apache. Haven't had any errors since. So I think that was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Author of ebooklib here.

Looking at the logs you are running Apache with mod_wsgi module and not uwsgi, so just ignore the solutions for uwsgi and focus on mod_wsgi. The problem here is that lxml is C extension module that uses simplified threading API for manipulation of the Python GIL and thus will not run correctly within any additional sub interpreters created by Python. Check the Apache mod_wsgi documentation for the solution (but it seems like you already tried that).

ebooklib does not pinpoint to the specific version of lxml, meaning you are using latest version of the lxml (meaning they have not changed the how they use API). If nothing else works maybe you could replace Apache and mod_wsgi with something that would work like nginx/apache with uwsgi. Worth to try considering the problems.